# Extremely high temperature on SSD

Tags: microcontroller, flash, nand-flash, ssd

I've got an SM941 SSD and it became dead after shutdown while writing data.
I decided to use up the nand flashes on it to DIY a new SSD.

Then I get an controller board(SM2246EN) with NGFF size, SATA interface, and I successfully resoldered the flashes onto that board. After using MP tool, I get a brand new SSD with nearly full SATA3 speed(550MB/s).

But the problem occurs, when I'm writing a lot of data to the SSD, the SSD becomes extremely hot, maximum temperature of 120C is detected after writing full 256GB data. When I'm reading, the temperature is still too high, about 80C after one 256GB cycle. It's not a sensor problem since it's really extremely hot when I put my finger on the controller, and my red thermometer do shows that it's about 110C on the package of the controller.

I've put it on to the test, for several times, writing and verifying the disk with no errors. So it seemed the temperature doesn't cause any problem.

But I still concerned about it, is it really normal for a controller to have a die temperature about 120C?

Comment: Who says 80 degrees C is too high? The datasheet will tell you what is too hot and what isn't. It might also help to get some heatsinking on the chip. Many boards will use PCB heatsinking, it could be that your controller board is just not well-designed. Without more information as to the specific boards and such it's hard to tell.

Comment: Commercial version of this IC only has an operating temperature range of 0-70C, and probably you didn't see that it exceeds 120 degrees C when it's writing at full speed.

Comment: Most packaging will act as a heat sink for high speed SSDs, also as Joren said, your controller PCB is probably cheap and does not have proper power/thermal planes.